# PHP resultado na mesma tela

Tags: php, css, bootstrap

Preciso que o resultado do formulário seja apresentado na mesma tela, fiz o seguinte código:

```
<?php
//Recolhe os valores digitados no formulário
$v = $_POST['valor'];
$tm = $_POST['txmensal'];
$p = $_POST['periodo'];

$ta = (((($tm/100)+1)**12)-1)*100;
?>
```

Aqui ... o form

```
        <form class="form form-control" method="POST">
        <h5 class="mt-2">Converter juros mensais para anuais</h5>
            <label for="valor" name="valor">Valor </label>
                <input type="text" name="valor" class="form-control">

            <label for="txmensal" name="txmensal" class="mt-1">Taxa Mensal </label>
                <input type="text" name="txmensal" class="form-control" placeholder="%">

            <label for="periodo" name="periodo" class="mt-1">Período </label>
                <input type="text" name="periodo" class="form-control" placeholder="meses">

            <input class="btn btn-default mt-1" type="submit" value="Submit">   

            <?php
                if ($_POST['submit']){?>
                     <div class="alert alert-success mt-4 text-center">
                         <?php echo 'A taxa anual é: ' .$ta?>
                    </div>
            <?php }?>
        </form>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste o código em texto não imagens, poste também o formulário que passa os dados para o php

Comment: Veja se está mais claro, tentei simplificar ainda mais o codigo, só verificando se o fomulario foi enviado

Comment: mude `if($_POST["submit"])` para `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))` `isset()` serve para saber se uma variável existe ou não (retorna um booleano), mas pelo que vejo acredito que uma aplicação com JavaScript seria mais simples rápida o proporcionaria uma experiência melhor para o usuário

Comment: Ele retorna o erro :da img

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme mencionado pelo Guilherme, nos comentários da pergunta, utilize a função `isset`, ela irá verificar se o valor existe ou não, por exemplo:

```
<?php

/* Se existir o índice `submit` em $_POST, então faça o cálculo */
if (isset($_POST['txmensal'])) {
    $v = $_POST['valor'];
    $tm = $_POST['txmensal'];
    $p = $_POST['periodo'];

    $ta = (((($tm/100)+1)**12)-1)*100;
}
/* Caso contrário, atribua NULL para à variável */
else {
    $ta = null;
}
?>
```

E para exibir, você pode utilizar o seguinte código

```
<?php
    /* Exiba o resultado caso a variável possua um valor diferente de null */
    if ($ta !== null) { ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success mt-4 text-center">
            <?php echo 'A taxa anual é: ' .$ta?>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

**Código completo:**

```
<?php

/* Se existir o índice `submit` em $_POST, então faça o cálculo */
if (isset($_POST['txmensal'])) {
    $v = $_POST['valor'];
    $tm = $_POST['txmensal'];
    $p = $_POST['periodo'];

    $ta = (((($tm/100)+1)**12)-1)*100;
}
/* Caso contrário, atribua NULL para à variável */
else {
    $ta = null;
}
?>
<form class="form form-control" method="POST">
    <h5 class="mt-2">Converter juros mensais para anuais</h5>

    <label for="valor" name="valor">Valor </label>
    <input type="text" name="valor" class="form-control">

    <label for="txmensal" name="txmensal" class="mt-1">Taxa Mensal </label>
    <input type="text" name="txmensal" class="form-control" placeholder="%">

    <label for="periodo" name="periodo" class="mt-1">Período </label>
    <input type="text" name="periodo" class="form-control" placeholder="meses">

    <input class="btn btn-default mt-1" type="submit" value="Submit">   

    <?php
        /* Exiba o resultado caso a variável possua um valor diferente de null */
        if ($ta !== null): ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success mt-4 text-center">
                <?php echo 'A taxa anual é: ' .$ta?>
            </div>
    <?php endif ?>
</form>
```

> O atributo `action`, quando você quer enviar os dados para a mesma página, ele torna-se opcional.

Comment: Esse aqui quase resolve completamente ! Mas ele não aparece o resultado, quando clico em Submit, nada acontece

Comment: @Flávia Editei minha resposta, adicionei o código completo.

Comment: Valdeir! Perfeito ! Pelo que vi .. o problema era o "endif" né... esse funcionou perfeitinho! Valew

Comment: @Flávia Ambos fazem a mesma coisa. Provavelmente algo não foi alterado durante a realização da explicação, acontece. rsrs

Answer (score 0):

Você quer que `$ta` seja exibida na tela? Se sim, o correto é usar o comando `echo`, o `return` apenas retorna o valor para ser usado em alguma função ou algo do gênero, não exibe nada.

Apenas troque o `return` por `echo`.

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/159374)

Comment: ok desumilde...

Comment: Devo concordar com o @hugocsl. Você falar de trocar `return` por `echo`, mas na instância atual da pergunta não encontrei nenhum `return`.

Answer (score -1):

Faz assim mano:

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['valor']) && isset($_POST['txmensal']) && isset($_POST['periodo']) ){
        $v = $_POST['valor'];
        $tm = $_POST['txmensal'];
        $p = $_POST['periodo'];

        $_POST['ta'] = (((($tm/100)+1)**12)-1)*100;

    }
    ?>


    <form class="form form-control" method="POST">
    <h5 class="mt-2">Converter juros mensais para anuais</h5>
        <label for="valor" name="valor">Valor </label>
            <input type="text" name="valor" class="form-control">

        <label for="txmensal" name="txmensal" class="mt-1">Taxa Mensal </label>
            <input type="text" name="txmensal" class="form-control" placeholder="%">

        <label for="periodo" name="periodo" class="mt-1">Período </label>
            <input type="text" name="periodo" class="form-control" placeholder="meses">

        <input class="btn btn-default mt-1" type="submit" value="Submit">   

        <?php
            if (isset($_POST)){
                 echo "<div class='alert alert-success mt-4 text-center'>A taxa anual é: " . $_POST['ta'] . "</div>";
            }
        ?>
    </form>
```